# Footer won't appear at all

Tags: html, css

I cant get `footer` to appear at all. I know that there is something small I'm missing out but what is it?

I played with positioning and display options but still no luck.

[JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2tvHH/)

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html
{
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333333;
}
.block 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.header
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f0a108;
}
.carousel
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #AADD66;
}
#carousel
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #BABABA;
}
.menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #CC11AA;
}
#menu
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #1CCACA;
}
.fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
.body
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 490px;
    background-color: #08a1f0;
}
#body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #BAC555;
}
.footer
{
    background-color: #19DE55;
}
#footer
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #08f018;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block header">
        <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    </div>

    <div class="block carousel">
        <div id="carousel">CAROUSEL</div>
    </div>

    <div class="block menu">
        <div id="menu">MENU</div>
    </div>

    <div class="block body">
        <div id="body">
            BEGIN
            <br />
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />Body
            <br />
            <br />END
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block footer">
        <div id="footer">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(window).on("scroll", function (e)
    {
        if (! $('.block.menu').hasClass('fixed'))
        {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 400)
            {
                $('.block.menu').addClass('fixed');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() < 400)
            {
                $('.block.menu').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is because you have all your elements with position:absolute, or fixed except the footer. So the footer will set himself on the top of the page behind the other elements...

Comment: `position: absolute;` to the body is causing that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your body is absolutely positionned, the footer sits right under the header, behind the carrousel.

You could wrap the body and footer and set the position: absolute on the wrapper to keep them grouped.

Comment: I did as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because all other content is positioned with a fixed or a absolute, you're footer is at the top underneath the header and menu.

Answer (score 0):

All the content div  is positioned with a fixed or a absolute,but footer is not positioned that's why is not appearing

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TKP6D/)**

```
.footer
{
    background-color: #19DE55;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```